# display H1 only after prompt answer is correct Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need Happy Birthday to display only after a user puts the right input in prompt (which is 30). I want it to be hidden by default. 
The reason I am doing it this way is that I want to add some CSS animation to this h1 tag later.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    var myTextbox = document.getElementById("bday");
    var Age = prompt("How old are you?:");
    if (Age == 30) {
      return myTextbox;
    } else {
      txt = "Really? ";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">HOW OLD ARE YOU?</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
<h2 id="bday"> Happy Birthday! </h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to complicate, you can do it with less markup and improved functionality:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myTextbox = document.getElementById("response");
  var Age = prompt("How old are you?");
  if (Age == 30) {
    myTextbox.innerHTML = "Happy Birthday!";
  } else if (Age == null) { // addition, if clicked on cancel
    myTextbox.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    myTextbox.innerHTML = "Really?";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">HOW OLD ARE YOU?</button>
<h1 id="response"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add hidden attribute to element with id = "bday"

```js
document.getElementById("bday").style.display = "none";

function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    var myTextbox = document.getElementById("bday");
    var Age = prompt("How old are you?:");
    if (Age == 30) {
      document.getElementById("bday").style.display = "block";
      return myTextbox;
    } else {
      txt = "Really? ";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
 
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">HOW OLD ARE YOU?</button>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
<h2 id="bday" hidden> Happy Birthday! </h2>
```